# java.lang.StackOverflowError while saving JPA entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA to save entities into a database. Below is code structure

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
@Data
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();

    public void add(Order order) {
        if(order != null) {
            if(orders == null) {
                this.orders = new HashSet<>();
            }
            this.orders.add(order);
            order.setCustomer(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**Order.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order")
@Data
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String orderTrackingNumber;
    private String status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Now I am trying to save customer along with its orders in database like below

**OrderService.java**

```
@Transactional
public PurchaseResponse placeOrder(Purchase purchase) {

    Order order = purchase.getOrder();

    String orderTrackingNumber = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    order.setOrderTrackingNumber(orderTrackingNumber);

    Customer customer = purchase.getCustomer();
    customer.add(order);

    this.customerRepository.save(customer);

    return new PurchaseResponse(orderTrackingNumber);
}
```

When `this.customerRepository.save(customer);` statement executes then I get following exception

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at com.ecomhunt.entities.Order.hashCode(Order.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:124) ~[na:na]
at com.ecomhunt.entities.Customer.hashCode(Customer.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
at com.ecomhunt.entities.Order.hashCode(Order.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:124) ~[na:na]
at com.ecomhunt.entities.Customer.hashCode(Customer.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
at com.ecomhunt.entities.Order.hashCode(Order.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:124) ~[na:na]
at com.ecomhunt.entities.Customer.hashCode(Customer.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
......
```

If I comment `order.setCustomer(this);` line in Customer#add(order), then error disappears but in database the `customer_id` is not save in order table.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@Data` annotation generates `equals` and `hashCode` methods relying on entity fields. When you placing `order` into `Customer#orders`, `HashSet` tries to compute `hashCode` of `Order`, `Order` refers to `Customer` which in turn refers to `Customer#orders` - that is why you are getting `SO`, basically you just need to correctly define `equals` and `hashCode` methods and do not rely on `lombok` magic.

[Using Primiry Key (id) while overriding equals() and hashCode() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869264/using-primiry-key-id-while-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-methods/)

Comment: Right. I changed `@Data` to `@Getter` and `@Setter`. Now it works fine. Thanks for pointing out the `lombok` limitation for JPA entities.

Comment: That is not a limitation of `lombok`, [it's configuration capabilities are extremely flexible](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode), take a look on `@EqualsAndHashCode` parameters: `of`, `callSuper`, `onlyExplicitlyIncluded`, the main problem here is to define those methods correctly for JPA entities, and there is no best answer how to do that properly.

Comment: As [this article](https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/) from Thorben Janssen states that, it is generally good idea to avoid using `Lombok` annotation on `Entity class`. Rather, we can use IDE to generate getter/setter and define certain method by ourselves as we wish.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the implicit `toString` feature of the `@Data` annotation was causing the StackOverFlow Error.

Remove your `@Data` Annotation and explicitly define the methods you want to use instead, e.g. `getter` and `setter` methods

Comment: please provide an example