# How to simulate lombok @data stackoverflow error within unit tests for repository class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, spring-repositories

I have a relationship between entities that throws a stack overflow error if the @Data annotation from Lombok is used instead of the individual @Getter and @Setter annotations. This is fixed now, but I would like to write a unit test for it within my repository tests. However, I'm not sure how to achieve that and haven't been able to find samples for it.

Here are my entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Builder
//@Getter
//@Setter
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_hobbies",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "hobby_and_interest_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<HobbyAndInterestEntity> hobbyAndInterestEntities;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hometown_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private HometownEntity hometownEntity;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hometown")
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HometownEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hometownEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false)
    private Set<UserEntity> userEntitySet;
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HobbyAndInterestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "hobbyAndInterestEntities")
    private Set<UserEntity> userEntities;
```

And here is my test for a case without the exception, which I was aiming to modify to test for the exception scenario:

```
    @Test
    void testGetUser() {

        UserEntity userEntity = saveUserEntity();

        assertTrue(userRepository.findAll().size() > 0);
        userEntity = userRepository.findById(userEntity.getId()).orElse(null);
        assertNotNull(userEntity);

        UserEntity finalUserEntity = userEntity;
        assertAll(
                () -> assertEquals("anyName", finalUserEntity.getName()),
                () -> assertEquals("anyCountry", finalUserEntity.getHometownEntity().getCountry()),
                () -> assertTrue(finalUserEntity.getHobbyAndInterestEntities().size() > 0));

        finalUserEntity.getHobbyAndInterestEntities().forEach(h -> assertEquals("anyInterest", h.getTitle()));
    }


    @NotNull
    private UserEntity saveUserEntity() {

        HometownEntity hometownEntity = HometownEntity.builder().city("anyCity").country("anyCountry").build();
        hometownEntity = hometownRepository.save(hometownEntity);

        HobbyAndInterestEntity hobbyAndInterestEntity = HobbyAndInterestEntity.builder()
                .title("anyInterest")
                .build();
        hobbyAndInterestEntity = hobbyAndInterestRepository.save(hobbyAndInterestEntity);
        Set<HobbyAndInterestEntity> hobbyAndInterestEntities = new HashSet<>();
        hobbyAndInterestEntities.add(hobbyAndInterestEntity);

        UserEntity userEntity = UserEntity.builder()
                .name("anyName")
                .hometownEntity(hometownEntity)
                .hobbyAndInterestEntities(hobbyAndInterestEntities)
                .build();

        return userRepository.save(userEntity);
    }
```

So in summary, I know the application is throwing the stack overflow when I have the @Data annotation and so I would like to write a test that would fail for it and pass again when I modify the entity class to use @Getter and @Setter, but not sure what is needed here and would appreciate some guidance, please.

Thank you very much.

Comment: your initial diagnosis of root cause seems to be too naive, that is not about [`@Data` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73078671/3426309), but about how you define `#equals` and `#hashCode` for entities. So, if we are talking about unit tests, you actually need to enforce "correct" definition of  `#equals` and `#hashCode` method for all entities.

Comment: Hi, sorry, not sure I understand what you mean by enforcing correct definition for the entities? But yes, you're correct, it's those methods included in the Data annotation that cause the Stack Overflow issue.

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question but are you not already there? Fixing the stackoverflow by adding `@EqualsAndHashCode( exclude = { "hobbyAndInterestEntities", "hometownEntity"}`  in your `UserEntity`. The Unitt-Test is then simply using `.equals()` or `.hashCode()`. The Stackoverflow will always be thrown as long as the problem is present.

Comment: Hi, my point is that I had the basic repository tests for my saving and retrieving and they all are passing while I had the @Data annotation but running the application would still throw the StackOverflow exception, so I'm trying to prevent this from happening again with some more robust test.

Comment: I understand your point about explicit tests for the equals and hashCode piece and I'll have a look at this, but as that's not explicitly called inside my application code I was wondering if there's some other way to test for this?

Answer (score -1):

Could you check `@Data` annotation [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data). `@Data` is a shortcut for `@ToString`, `@EqualsAndHashCode`, `@Getter` on all fields, @Setter on all non-final fields, and `@RequiredArgsConstructor`! When you call `toString` or `equals` or `hashCode` method, the relationship entities will query in the database. You can try to review generated source, the relationship entities is used in those methods. I think it can throw a stack overflow error.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but the question is not really about the application code, but how to test for it.

Comment: I know the application is throwing the stack overflow when I have the @Data annotation and so I want to write a test that would fail for it and pass when I modify the entity class to use Getter and Setter.